# IIS Reverse Proxy forwarding Authorization header

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, http-headers, iis-7.5, reverse-proxy

We are using IIS Aplication Request routing and URL Rewrite rules to reverse proxy access to an internal webserver.

This works when IIS is configured with Anonymous authentication, but adding Basic Authentication causes problems. Without getting into too much detail about the internal webserver's authentication mechanisms, what I would like to do is *not* pass the Authorization Header from the IIS Proxy to the target webserver.

```
clientIP    proxyIP     HTTP    GET /resource HTTP/1.1
    Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
    ...
    Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedCredentials 
    ....
proxyIP     serverIP    HTTP        GET /resource HTTP/1.1
    Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
    ...
    Authorization: Basic Base64EncodedCredentials <--need to remove this
    ....
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!